# How to see script inside VIEW in MDB

Tags: ms-access

Hi I have an MDB file and it consist of VIEWS. I am using "MDB Viewer Plus" to explore the tables and Views. But I can see only records from the view but I do not see the SQL script used in the VIEW.

Kindly guide. How to see the script? Hope this is valid question. I have did enough try.

### Solved

I used Microsoft Access and now I can see the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in the update to your question, the most straightforward way to view the SQL statement for a saved query (View) in an Access database (`.mdb` or `.accdb` file) is to open it in Access, open the query in Design View, and then switch to SQL View:

[image: sqlView.png]